# Sip register user in twilio

Tags: twilio

I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Your TwiML tried to Dial a Twilio SIP Registered User that is not currently registered
```

Apparently my SIP Registered user is not being recongized.

In SIP Domains I've created a sip uri

```
myexample.sip.twilio.com
```

I then create a credentials list with my username

```
Example Usr
+13105551212
password
```

In sip registration I have enabled it with
SIP Registration Authentication using `Example Usr`

I then have this twiml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial answerOnBridge="true">
    <Sip>
      {{To}}@myexample.sip.us1.twilio.com
    </Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

I have also tried `{{To}}@myexample.siptwilio.com` and

+13105551212@myexample.sip.us1.twilio.com

When I dial the number associated with this I get the error mentioned above.

```
Error - 32009
Dialing SIP Endpoint failure - User not registered
```

The error also says:

```
Prior to dialing, you can verify that your SIP Endpoint has successfully registered in the Console "Registered SIP Endpoints" tab found on the SIP Domains page.
```

When I go to the page "Registered SIP Endpoints" There is nothing on this page, no users listed.
Am I missing a step to register the sip end point?  Any idea what I"m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your previous screenshot, change outgoing call without registration to no. Most likely your SIP Softphone is not registering.

[image]